Short story: Sci-Fi pilot discovers a massacre investigating mysterious signal
It's been years since I read this short story, I apologize if this is fuzzy or incorrect but it's been bugging me all day and I'd like to know what I read.
A pilot in a high-tech jet/spacecraft flies at breakneck speeds to investigate a mysterious signal. I believe there is a segment about how the craft changes shape in order to address possible reentry into atmosphere or landing. Upon landing, they discover that at the source of the signal is a transmission device near what appears to be an empty settlement or outpost.
However they quickly discover that the settlement is not empty. Instead its populace are all in twisted forms of agonized death. The mystery grows as the pilot tries to determine how these people died. There are no marks on their bodies. There is no sign of damage anywhere.
I do not remember the ending of the short story. Only that the pilot is lost in trying to figure out what happened.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?  Did you read it in a magazine, an anthology, or online?

I'm sorry but I think it's been at least a decade since I came across it. I can't remember anything else without fearing I'd misremember a detail.
